# Clearing the previous drawing when you change the length value on the triangle, html canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to clear my canvas every time I change my triangle's length value via the range input? Whenever I change the range input, it doesn't remove the lines previous to changing the range.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="800" height="400" >
        </canvas>
        <label for="b_range">change the length of b:</label>
        <input id="b_range" type="range" min="10" max="150" value="150" oninput="update()">
    </div>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
        var range = document.getElementById("b_range");
        var val = 150;
 
        function update() {
            val = range.value;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.moveTo(500, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(val, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 250);
            ctx.moveTo(480, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(480 ,230);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 230);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.font = 'bold 20px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText("b", 335, 270);
        }
        ctx.moveTo(500, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(val, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(500, 250);
        ctx.moveTo(480, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(480 ,230);
        ctx.lineTo(500, 230);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.font = 'bold 20px Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText("b", 335, 270);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe, you can try it with the canvas method, restore();

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a `ctx.beginPath();` in front of the `ctx.moveTo(500, 250);`.
In order to draw a line you have to first call the `beginPath()` method so that it will know where to begin your line. But there is a easier way to write the code, try out this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="800" height="400" >
        </canvas>
        <label for="b_range">change the length of b:</label>
        <input id="b_range" type="range" min="10" max="150" value="150">
    </div>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
        var range = document.getElementById("b_range");
        var val = 150;
 
        function update() {
            val = range.value;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(500, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(val, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 250);
            ctx.moveTo(480, 250);
            ctx.lineTo(480 ,230);
            ctx.lineTo(500, 230);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.font = 'bold 20px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText("b", 335, 270);
            requestAnimationFrame(update)
        }
        update()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use `requestAnimationFrame(update)` which will draw around 60 frames per second, which is perfect for making animations and I also deleted the same lines of code that was outside of the update function since it will draw repeatedly.
Hope it helps.